# How to handle blob column in TypeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have a MySQL database that stores profile images of users. The user info should be provided via REST API that is implemented as a Node.js server. I use TypeORM for accessing the database.

I want to deliver the image info as base64 string via REST API. How could I achieve this?

I mapped the blob column as a Buffer in my entity. Do I have to convert the data to base64 using a listener on the property?

Comment: No one ever used TypeORM with blob columns?

Comment: Yes, only your question helped me find it, years later. Tell me if you find any better technique than this.

Comment: No, but to be honest, I did not search for an alternative solution :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution that works for me:

I load the user object and the image is loaded into a string variable. Before I deliver the object I convert it into a Buffer and encode it base64:

```
Buffer.from(user.profileImage).toString('base64');
```

Answer (score 2):

For a cleaner code, you can try using a transformer.
Here's a usage example for saving and retrieving a string from a blob column.

```
  @Column({
    transformer: {
      to: (value: string) => Buffer.from(value),
      from: (value: Buffer) => value.toString()
    }
   })
  longText?: string;
```